# FAILURE response when sharing an url

Tags: share, linkedin-api

I'm having trouble sharing my urls to Linkedin. When I try to share the url to my site (or any other directory of my site): **http://www.eventioz.com.ar**, the sharer seems to get into an infinite loop making a get request to the following url:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/secure/share?urlForShareTicketCompleted=&tid=dSoOoPgQcChzpz4UbjARpC8JozwQd2RzdP4Mbj4Odz5Bp3dB&sctx=O&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eeventioz%2Ecom%2Ear&title=Test&summary=This+is+a+test&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2FshareArticle%3Fmini%3Dtrue%26url%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eeventioz%2Ecom%2Ear%26title%3DTest%26summary%3DThis%2520is%2520a%2520test%26source%3D&trk=LI_BADGE_OLD
```

The sharer popup shows a spinning wheel. The response to the browser is:

```
<WSResponse>
<status type="error" key="ShareServlet.addArticleUrl.failure">Your request couldn&#39;t be completed.</status>

<responseInfo>FAILURE</responseInfo>
<responseMsg>Your request couldn&#39;t be completed.</responseMsg>
<jsonPayLoad></jsonPayLoad>

</WSResponse>
```

And the popup keeps making get requests to the url indefinitely.

This worked fine until a few days ago. My og tags seems to be OK. I've tried several share buttons generators but they all show the same behaviour.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have solved by itself. Apparently it was a bug in Linkedin page **scraper**.